# "Multi-key" dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map

I was making a relatively large-scale project in Python as a learning experiment, and in the process I found that it would be useful to have a map (or, in Python, I guess they're called dictionaries) where a value could have multiple keys.  I couldn't find much support for this out there, so this is the implementation I ended up going with:

```
def range_dict(*args):
    return_val = {}
    for k,v in args:
        for i in k:
            return_val[i] = v
    return return_val

COINS = range_dict((range(1,15), None),
                     (range(15,30), "1d6x1000 cp"),
                     (range(30,53), "1d8x100 sp"),
                     (range(53,96), "2d8x10 gp"),
                     (range(96,101), "1d4x10 pp"))
```

I was told that this wasn't really a good way to achieve what I wanted to do, but I don't really understand *why*.  It works perfectly in my application.  What's wrong with this?  Is there a better, more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: It's hard to answer if the structure is optimal, because there is no data how many values there are? How many keys per value? How many unique values? Are ranges usual or an exception? Also, which operations are prevailing and so on. Are you optimizing for speed or memory conservation?

Comment: "I was told that this wasn't really a good way to achieve what I wanted to do". Well, what *do* you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize what I'm doing was so confusing.  Basically, I wanted a dictionary where a value would be mapped to multiple keys.  So the numbers 1-14 should map to `None`, 15-30 should map to `1d6x1000 cp`, etc.  Thought it was pretty self-explanatory. :(

Comment: Yes, that's all clear from your post. But what do you want to *do* with this data structure? It looks like a table in an RPG that you are doing to roll d100 against.

Comment: @JeffGohlke I think you can also use dictionary comprehensions, it's the same as my answer down below but is build like a comprehension dict. List comprehensions are faster than for loop block. Dictionary comprehension should be faster too, I think. Check them out.

Comment: @GarethRees Ah, gotcha.  Yeah, it's actually a loot generator for D&D 3.5.  And the `COINS` variable is actually a dictionary of `range_dict`s, but I just thought that would confuse the example since that's pretty irrelevant.  But the way I use it in the code is like `COINS[5][d100()]`, where `5` is the Challenge Rating and `d100()` generates a random number between 1 and 100.

Comment: @dragons And thanks, I will. :)  Thanks for your answer as well.  Just want to leave the question open for a bit.

Comment: I know it is a dead topic irregardless, as is mentioned in other answers, your ranges you originally provided were ambiguous. If you roll a 15 is that None or "1d6x1000 cp". Same goes for if you "roll" a 30, 53 or a 96.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### 1. Comments on your code

1. No docstrings! What does your code do and how am I supposed to use it?
2. No test cases. This ought to be a good opportunity to use [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).
3. Given that your purpose here is to implement RPG lookup tables, your design seems a bit hard to use. The printed RPG table probably says something like this:

   ```
   1-8     giant spider
   9-12    skeleton
   13-18   brass dragon
   ...
   ```

   but you have to input it like this (adding one to the limit of each range):

   ```
   range_dict((range(1, 9), "giant spider"),
              (range(9, 13), "skeleton"),
              (range(13, 18), "brass dragon"),
              ...)
   ```

   which would be easy to get wrong.
4. The design also seems fragile, because it doesn't ensure that the ranges are contiguous. If you made a data entry mistake:

   ```
   d = range_dict((range(1, 8), "giant spider"),
                  (range(9, 13), "skeleton"),
                  (range(13, 18), "brass dragon"),
                  ...)
   ```

   then the missing key would later result in an error:

   ```
   >>> d[8]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   KeyError: 8
   ```

### 2. An alternative approach

Here's how I'd implement this lookup table:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from collections.abc import Mapping

class LookupTable(Mapping):
    """A lookup table with contiguous ranges of small positive integers as
    keys. Initialize a table by passing pairs (max, value) as
    arguments. The first range starts at 1, and second and subsequent
    ranges start at the end of the previous range.

    >>> t = LookupTable((10, '1-10'), (35, '11-35'), (100, '36-100'))
    >>> t[10], t[11], t[100]
    ('1-10', '11-35', '36-100')
    >>> t[0]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    KeyError: 0
    >>> next(iter(t.items()))
    (1, '1-10')

    """
    def __init__(self, *table):
        self.table = sorted(table)
        self.max = self.table[-1][0]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = int(key)
        if not 1 <= key <= self.max:
            raise KeyError(key)
        return self.table[bisect_left(self.table, (key,))][1]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(range(1, self.max + 1))

    def __len__(self):
        return self.max
```

Notes on this implementation:

1. The constructor takes the maximum for each range (not the maximum plus one), making data entry less error-prone.
2. The minimum of each range is taken from the end of the previous range, thus ensuring that there are no gaps between ranges.
3. The [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) abstract base class provides much of the functionality of a read-only dictionary. The idea is that you supply the `__getitem__`, `__iter__` and `__len__` methods, and the `Mapping` class supplies implementations of `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__` methods for you. (Which you can override if you need to, but that's not necessary here.)
4. I've used [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) to efficiently look up keys in the sorted table.

Answer (score 6):

So, I came across this issue earlier today. Wasn't real thrilled with most of the solutions here, mostly because I wanted to be able to set normal keys, but also set a range of keys all at once when needed, so I came up with this:

```
class RangedDict(dict):
    """
    A dictionary that supports setting items en masse by ranges, but also supports normal keys.

    The core difference between this and any other dict is that by passing a tuple of 2 to 3 numeric values, an
    inclusive range of keys will be set to that value. An example usage is:

    >>> d = RangedDict({
    ...   (1, 5): "foo"
    ... })
    >>> print d[1]  # prints "foo"
    >>> print d[4]  # also prints "foo"
    >>> print d[5]  # still prints "foo" because ranges are inclusive by default
    >>> d['bar'] = 'baz'
    >>> print d['bar']  # prints 'baz' because this also works like a normal dict

    Do note, ranges are inclusive by default, so 5 is also set. You can control
    inclusivity via the `exclusive` kwarg.

    The third, optional, parameter that can be given to a range tuple is a step parameter (analogous to the step
    parameter in xrange), like so: `(1, 5, 2)`, which would set keys 1, 3, and 5 only. For example:

    >>> d[(11, 15, 2)] = "bar"
    >>> print d[13]  # prints "bar"
    >>> print d[14]  # raises KeyError because of step parameter

    NOTE: ALL tuples are strictly interpreted as attempts to set a range tuple. This means that any tuple that does NOT
    conform to the range tuple definition above (e.g., `("foo",)`) will raise a ValueError.
    """
    def __init__(self, data=None, exclusive=False):
        # we add data as a param so you can just wrap a dict literal in the class constructor and it works, instead of
        # having to use kwargs
        self._stop_offset = 0 if exclusive else 1
        if data is None:
            data = {}

        for k, v in data.items():
            if isinstance(k, tuple):
                self._store_tuple(k, v)
            else:
                self[k] = v

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            self._store_tuple(key, value)
        else:
            # let's go ahead and prevent that infinite recursion, mmmmmkay
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def _store_tuple(self, _tuple, value):
        if len(_tuple) > 3 or len(_tuple) < 2:
            # eventually, it would be nice to allow people to store tuples as keys too. Make a new class like: RangeKey
            # to do this
            raise ValueError("Key: {} is invalid! Ranges are described like: (start, stop[, step])")

        step = _tuple[2] if len(_tuple) == 3 else 1
        start = _tuple[0]
        stop = _tuple[1]

        # +1 for inclusivity
        for idx in xrange(start, stop + self._stop_offset, step):
            dict.__setitem__(self, idx, value)
```

It uses tuples to describe ranges, which looks rather elegant, if I do say so myself. So, some sample usage is:

```
d = RangedDict()
d[(1, 15)] = None
d[(15, 25)] = "1d6x1000 cp"
```

Now you can easily use `d[4]` and get what you want.

The astute reader will however notice that this implementation does **not** allow you to use tuples as keys **at all** in your dict. I don't see that as a common use case, or something elegant to do, in general, so I felt it was worth the tradeoff. However, a new class could be made named along the lines of `RangeKey(1, 5, step=2)` that could be used to key ranges, thus letting you key tuples as well.

I hope a future reader enjoys my code!

Comment: While I like this approach quite a bit, the inclusiveness of the upper boundary might be surprising to a user. How about making that optional by using `self._end_offset = 1 if inclusive else 0` instead of the constant +1 in `_store_tuple`, with `inclusive=True/False` as parameter to `__init__`?

Comment: Edited to accommodate that.

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan of the `exclusive` switch (I mean over using `inclusive`) with a `False` default. Double-negative is usually not straight forward... Any reason why you preferred that combination?

Comment: I would argue that `exclusive` isn't really a negative by itself, so this isn't really a double negative. I mostly chose `exclusive` because it was already inclusive by default, and I think a clearer API is one that is opt-IN and not opt-OUT. For example, to me it makes more sense and is more common to pass a Truthy flag to change behavior, rather than a Falsey one.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. De gustibus non disputandum est ;)

Comment: Definitely one of the toughest parts about software design: creating a common convention and base for naming =).

Answer (score 4):

The main drawback to this arrangement is that it's wasteful. For a small case it's not a big deal but for a large range of values you're going to need an equally large range of keys, which will mean both a lot of searching for the right key and also expending memory to store all the keys.

For the specific application the python [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module is handy. It's great for fast searching through *sorted* data, so its fast for this kind of lookup table:

```
import bisect

# Set up the data. Don't do it inside the function, you don't
# want to do it over and over in the function!
xp_table = [(0, 0), (15, "1d6x1000 cp"), (30, "1d8x100 sp"), (53, "2d8x10 gp"), (96 ,"1d4x10 pp")]
xp_table.sort() 
keys = [k[0] for k in xp_table]

def get_reward(val):
    idx = bisect.bisect_right(keys, val)
        return xp_table[idx][1]
```

A dictionary based solution will still be better for data that doesn't sort, or does not fall into neat ranges.

Answer (score 3):

My attempt, keep in my mind that I'm not close to any of pro's around here.

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i < 15:
        my_coins[i] = None
    if 15 <= i < 30:
        my_coins[i] = '1d6x1000 cp'
    if 30 <= i < 53:
        my_coins[i] = '1d8x100 sp'
    if 53 <= i < 96:
        my_coins[i] = '2d8x10 gp'
    if i >= 96:
        my_coins[i] = '1d4x10 pp'
```

Put it in a function and return `my_coins`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of doing this, but I wanted something a bit more concise.  And I figured I could create a convenient data structure that just represented the table.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Your original function have 5 parameters. Usualy a good design is to have a up to maximum 4.

Answer (score 2):

If everything wanted with the datasctructure is to be able to generate random coin, it's much easier to do directly by generating random integer number from [1, 100] and then use if-statements to go through choices (ranges).

Another possibility is to have all the values in a list as many times as their range length and use [random.choice() function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) to fetch one.

Also, I do not find the original code particularly bad. Write tests, experiment, and you are there.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question: One drawback of a multi-key map is that more memory is used to store the second key.

However. here is a way to get your desired functionality:

```
d = { # key is max value
    5: 'one',
    10: 'two',
    15: 'three',
    20: 'four',
    25: 'five',
    30: 'six'}

MINIMUM = 1

for i in range(10):
    d[[key for key in sorted(d) if key >=random.randint(MINIMUM, max(d))][0]]

'two'
'four'
'two'
'five'
'three'
'three'
'five'
'four'
'three'
'four'
```

You could replace the part sorted(d) with `one_off_pre_sorted_keys`:

```
one_off_pre_sorted_keys = sorted(d)
```